# Plotting an 1803 Kentucky deed survey

Tags: qgis-3, metes-and-bounds

I'm a beginner and  know little about GIS.
I'm at the end of my rope for what should be a simple one-off project.

GOAL:

To start at the beginning, I'm trying to plot my ancestor's deed survey from 1803 Kentucky to figure out exactly where it is. It's in "metes and bounds" as they say, more specifically bearings and poles (rods), but there's no point of origin except for a "beech and poplar" plus the name of the creek it's on.

My goal is to plot this survey, plus 4 more surrounding surveys and fit them all together, and then be able to drag them around on top of a stream map in order to fit the survey boundaries up against the creek and hopefully get a reasonable point of origin.

TRIED SO FAR:

So far I've done the following:

1. Using "legallandconverter.com, I've converted the directions and distances into lat/longs. It only outputs in WGS84, not NAD83. This nice little web program actually plots the polygons onto a map of choice, but it's tedious to then move the polys around to fit against the stream, as that involves best-guess shifting the lat/lon starting point over and over a few feet at a time, plus it only shows one layer at a time.
2. QGIS (3.28):
   I've read the manual, sat thru hours of video tutorials, scoured the web forums for answers to similar problems (as well as beginner's how-to's), and am really struggling with this. (I'm sticking to free apps as it makes no sense to spend big bucks on a one-off project.)

I can't find that QGIS can intake rods or poles, so am using the WGS84 lat/longs with a best-guess starting point.

There's simply no tutorial nor instructions that I can find on how to do this.

So far I've accomplished:

1. Input the points as a layer.
2. Points to Path as a (closed) second layer.
3. Lines to Polygons as a third layer.

As best I can understand, to be able to drag a poly around, it must be a "feature", so...

4. Export Poly layer as MapInfo Tab.
5. Toggle editing.
6. This activates the Move Feature tool.

So now I can shove them around in relation to each other.

QUESTION: Is there a better and simpler way to do this whole process?

I'm making progress by blundering around like a blind man, but I'm afraid I'm missing some critical steps or doing unneccessary things.

UPDATE: I just realized I should be acquiring/plotting the points of the nearby stream in order to align the surveys, so looking into that...

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. A complex, multi-faceted, (and somewhat opinion-based) set of questions is not a good fit for our Focused question/Best answer model.

Comment: Please be aware that rivers make very bad entities for referencing, since they tend to shift their course.

Comment: I don't know if Beech's and Poplars live to be 220+ years old, but even if they did, do you know exactly which trees defined the Point of Beginning? And any property line defined by a stream will change as the stream changes. Also, bearings from that time will almost certainly be by compass, so you'll need to correct for that. You really need a surveyor.

Comment: Good point, Pointdump. No to your first question. I only found the survey after I had visited the area, but I would just assume all the trees referenced aren't there anymore. I never thought about compass degrees changing over time, but guess they would. I'll have to study up on that, thanks.

Comment: Erik - I figured streams & creeks change, but this one actually fits (somewhat) along one of the survey boundaries I have, so may not have changed much. It's a small creek with not much flow (at least when i saw it last year).